# How do I use the custom prelude from NoRedInk with stack?

Tags: haskell, elm, haskell-stack

I'm trying to write a desktop program using an elm frontend with haskell backend.
To make writing the backend code idiomatically similar to the front end code (and make sending data between them easier), it would be great to use [No Red Ink's custom prelude](https://github.com/NoRedInk/haskell-libraries/tree/trunk/nri-prelude).

Stack is my build tool.

It's the first time I've tried to use a custom prelude. I can't get it to even turn up. The key unresolvable error message for me is the one with no suggested "different approaches to resolving this":

```
In the dependencies for nri-prelude-0.6.0.6:
    unix is a library dependency, but the package provides no library`
```

---

Here's everything I tried:

I tried adding `-fplugin=NriPrelude.Plugin` to my ghc options in my `stack.yaml` but it said

```
 <command line>: Could not find module `NriPrelude.Plugin'
```

So I tried adding `nri-prelude` to my dependencies, resulting in a recommendation to add

```
- nri-prelude-0.6.0.6@sha256:4ccc7488149a0401a9241c9b64db22c48a8639afaae11cffb263da5226e8acde,5289
```

to my `stack.yaml`, which resulted in a recommendation to add

```
- terminfo-0.4.1.5@sha256:4d1790aeb354797955ca1cb67035ca80f66a0d9cc4e43a51c1c9d566e00ce350,1713
- unix-2.7.3@sha256:20079c504d0ca33fbf11de3a215d25220c8d43499a93049a8f2791323f3bd57b,6047
```

as well. This was a dead end for me because I got the error message:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for nri-prelude-0.6.0.6:
    unix is a library dependency, but the package provides no library
needed due to Experiment-0.1.0.0 -> nri-prelude-0.6.0.6

Some different approaches to resolving this:


Plan construction failed.
```

I couldn't help but notice the empty list of approaches to resolving it this time.

---

Instead of going down that route I tried using a route that had worked for another library, by putting

```
  - github:  NoRedInk/haskell-libraries
    commit: a202da122192ad2b9435f92086f5b4c5e304531b
```

in my `stack.yaml`. It didn't like that:

```
No cabal file found for Archive from https://github.com/NoRedInk/haskell-libraries/archive/a202da122192ad2b9435f92086f5b4c5e304531b.tar.gz
```

and when I tried

```
  - github:  NoRedInk/haskell-libraries/nri-prelude
    commit: 8657ef0ea153a12fcaa0d048be98598512fe9df6
```

that didn't even parse:

```
Could not parse 'stack.yaml':
Aeson exception:
Error in $['extra-deps'][3]: failed to parse field 'extra-deps': parsing Text failed, expected String, but encountered Object
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? `unix` doesn't work on Windows, and since `nri-prelude` depends on it, it won't work on Windows either.

Comment: Wow, why would a general-purpose library require hard dependency on `unix`? Quite baffling to me.

Comment: Oh yikes, yes I'm on Windows.

Comment: @Abastro It has some little logging thing in Platform/DevLog.hs that ensures that the hard coded file /tmp/nri-prelude-logs has System.Posix.stdFileMode before appending to it. That's an annoying needlessly OS specific way of doing that. System.Directory has OS-relevant, sometimes user specific locations in it. Hard coding a linux file path isn't necessary

Comment: @AndrewC yep, agreed. Sad how they went with it.